# Displaying Document Totals in Category View

Tags: mysql, count

Hello All Gurus out there.

This is probably the simplest thing out there, but I am struggling to find the answer.

Basically, I have two tables, structured like this:

Table 1:

```
categories_docs
|    CATID    |    parent    |    name    |
| 1           | 0            | Cars       |
| 2           | 0            | Bikes      |
| 3           | 1            | VW         |
| 4           | 1            | Toyota     |
| 5           | 2            | Honda      |
| 6           | 2            | Yamaha     |
```

Table 2:

```
docs
|    DOCID    |  categories  |    title                         |
| 1           | 3            | GTI User Manual                  |
| 2           | 3            | Polo GTi Performance Tweaks      |
| 3           | 4            | Hilux 4x4 Cheat Guide            |
| 4           | 4            | Supra TuneUp                     |
| 5           | 5            | CBR600 Service Manual            |
| 6           | 5            | CBR1000RR Service Manual         |
```

Essentially, they following should output:

> Cars (4)
>
> > VW (2)
> >
> > TOYOTA (2)
>
> Bikes (2)
>
> > Honda (1)
> >
> > Yamaha (0)

Currently I have the list view working, but I am struggling to get it to count the totals.

Query to list categories:

```
function insert_get_categories($a)
{
global $config,$conn;
$query = "select * from categories_docs where parent='0' order by name asc"; 
$results = $conn->execute($query);
$returnthis = $results->getrows();
return $returnthis;
}
```

The TPL wich renders the PHP: (Using Smarty)

```
{insert name=get_categories assign=listcats}
    {section name=o loop=$listcats}
        <div class="column {if $smarty.section.o.iteration % 6 == 0}last{/if}"><br>
             <h3><a href="{$baseurl}/subcategory.php?id={$listcats[o].CATID}">  {$listcats[o].name|stripslashes}</a></h3>
        </div>
    {/section}
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Note that, by convention, we use NULL and not 0 to represent orphans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query I used was:

```
SELECT *,IFNULL(COUNT(D.CATEGORIES),0) as total FROM categories_docs AS CD LEFT JOIN docs AS D ON D.categories=CD.CATID WHERE CD.PARENT = 0 GROUP BY CD.CATID
```

Thanks for your help Melon!!

Comment: Ur welcome. I think u shuld put this editing the question rather than puting an answer

Answer (score 1):

im not a guru but maybe this help you a bit:

this sql give the totals of direct categories:

```
select CATID,parent,name,count(*) from categories_docs inner join docs on categories=CATID group by CATID;
```

this one give you the total of first level parent categories:

```
select count(*),cd2.name from categories_docs cd1 inner join docs on categories=CATID join categories_docs cd2 on cd2.CATID=cd1.parent group by parent
```

if you whant to show them all togheter use UNION ALL

```
select name,IF(isnull(DOCID) and parent !=0, 0, count(*)) as amount  from categories_docs left join docs on categories=CATID where parent!=0 group by CATID
UNION ALL
select cd2.name,IF(isnull(DOCID), 0, count(*)) from categories_docs cd1 inner join docs on categories=CATID join categories_docs cd2 on cd2.CATID=cd1.parent group by cd1.parent
```

edit: I made a bit change on the last sql to show also child-categories with no elements

Comment: Hi Melon, 

The only query that works is the first and this does 99% what I need it to do.

The other 1% is the fact it does not list categories if it has no docs inside it. Is there a way to get it to list "category name (0)" instead of removing the category completely?

At the moment, I have about 20 categories, about 12 of them have documents in them. It should display all 20 and not just 12. 

Thanks so much so far.

Comment: maybe they dont work cause i miss the ; at the end. I make a copy of your tables using the rows you give and its works for me. And yes, there is a way to do it, more than one (i think) i´ll try to get it.

Comment: the last sql should do it.

Comment: Hi Melon, Unfortunately the last two queries don't work at all. They simply display a blank page :(

Comment: IF I run: 
"SELECT *, COUNT(*) as total FROM categories_docs LEFT OUTER JOIN docs ON categories=CATID WHERE parent=0 GROUP BY CATID ORDER BY name asc"

Instead have returning nothing, I get (1) (which I am assuming is for null)? I now need to somehow get (1) to be (0)

Comment: what abaut get the row tables from database and make the calculations with php ? (i see you are using php)

Comment: BOOYA!! I figured it out!